# S3 GetObject does not return response

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch an object from a s3 bucket. However I don't get a response, but also no error logged in the console.

```
function test(filename) {
        return new Promise((resolve => {

            var params = {
                 Bucket: bucket, 
                 Key: "pptSource/"+filename
            };

            s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
                // Handle any error and exit
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

              resolve(data.Body);
            });
        }));
    }
```

I call the function in following function:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

        function test(filename) { .. }

        async function run() {
                var sourceFile = "XX_company_presentation_2019_v1~1-2.pptx";
                var filename = sourceFile;

                var pptSource = await test(filename);
                console.log(pptSource);
        }

        run();
}
```

and get following log

```
END RequestId: 078fcfaf-949d-4231-9bcb-a35d40ffd3a3
REPORT RequestId: 078fcfaf-949d-4231-9bcb-a35d40ffd3a3  Duration: 34.78 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 106 MB
```

Comment: Quick side node... the S3 library will return a promise all on its own.  `s3.getObject(...).promise()`.

Comment: Your lambda is being closed before getobject gets the file, Please provide the full context of how you are calling the test function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically you are not waiting for the run function to complete.

Change it to

```
await run();
```

This will wait for the `Promise` to resolve